# How do I append more elements to an ENUM-type in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, enums, mysql-workbench

As the title suggests, i'm trying to add more elements to my existing ENUM-type column. I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3 for my database.

```
CREATE TABLE `quantum` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` enum('a','b','c','d','e') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11173 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

then I try to alter type column to add another element `f`

```
ALTER TABLE quantum
MODIFY COLUMN type enum('a','b','c','d','e','f') NOT NULL
```

then MySQL Workbench 6.3 is giving me some weird error

[image]

Comment: `type` is a reserved word, so as a column name (bad idea, btw) it probably needs to be specified as \`type\` with backticks to escape it.

Comment: Do you want to use a GUI tool (as in question title) or plain SQL code (as in question body)?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - [Not really](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html). It's a keyword but not a reserved one. Code above works fine for me in MySQL/5.5.46. In fact, now I wonder if the OP actually tried to run the code and got a server error or he's merely asking about the client-side parser.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you for pointing that out.  Bad guess. :(  I really cannot fathom what Oracle must be thinking with a client-side parser -- *what could possibly go wrong?* I wondered what was going on with non-MySQL-looking error messages I had been seeing here on SO.  That's a tragic design decision, if that's what they're doing.  The old MySQL Query Browser still is, as always, my go-to tool as a DBA -- light, fast, unbloated. Show me the objects and let me run queries and scripts.  If the server doesn't like them, let the server tell me. Otherwise, out of my way, no issues like this.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Well... I do like syntax highlighting and linting and any other help I can get. And Workbench logic should be rather good because it basically reuses most components from server code.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is great.  Calling out imaginary errors, and displaying error messages that are meaningless to actual MySQL experts is not quite as commendable.  But, then, workbench has a long history of trying to do "helpful" things it shouldn't try to do, doing them poorly, and often sluggishly.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have the latest version of MySQL Workbench. I don't see this problem in the current one (6.3.6):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While using enum() datatype in workbench/ mysql. Mysql do not aceept ENUM() with no values/params inside the ENUM().

Use ENUM with some comma separated values :

```
ENUM('PENDING','SUCCESS','FAIL')
```

[image]